# Can the same UITableviewcell be used in multiple UITableViews?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4

What I want to ask you is **"Can one `UITableviewcell` be used for multiple `tableview` like viewholder that can use anytime for recyclerview in android?"**  what I used to do is in one `viewcontroller` I have a `tableview` with a custom Cell and gave its identifier as normal but if I trying to use another `uitableview` in another `Viewcontroller` with that cell that inside the previous tableview, it always gives me a blank cell with white background. is there a way to use it like that?

**EDIT:** Here is what my tableview look like when i've already set cellforrow for it already.
[Click to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zd4eW.jpg) and here what my cell look like [Click to view cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8YtU.png) and here are my code for different cell in a tableview, **It'll work if i use use those 2 cell in current tableview**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if indexPath.section == 0{
            let cell = self.mytable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! HistoryItemTableCell
            let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: cell.frame.maxY, width: cell.frame.size.width, height: cell.frame.size.height))
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.3)
            cell.selectedBackgroundView = view

            let order = OrderItemObj
            cell.num_of_day.text = "\(order.ticket_type.name)"
            cell.ref_num.text = order.order_tx_number
            cell.quantity.text = order.number_tickets
            cell.price.text = "$\(order.ticket_type.price).00 USD"

            if order.status == "unpaid"{
                cell.ic_status.image = UIImage(named: "ic_status_unpaid")
            }else{
                cell.ic_status.image = UIImage(named: "ic_status_paid")
            }
            cell.start_date.text = "\(order.start_date)"
            cell.end_date.text = "\(order.expired_date)"
            return cell
        }else{
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! OrderDetailTicketCell
            let t = listTicket[indexPath.row]
            cell.dob.text = t.dob
            cell.gender.text = t.sex
            cell.nation.text = t.nationality
            let url = URL(string: t.photo)
            cell.imageN.kf.setImage(with: url)
            return cell
        }
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0 {
            return 3
        }else{
            return self.listTicket.count
        }
    }
override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mytable.register(HistoryItemTableCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

        ViewHistoryItem()
        mytable.dataSource = self
        mytable.delegate = self

    }
```

Comment: Yes you can use it. Show what you have tried.

Comment: You can do it by creating custom cell class in XIB and registering nib.

Comment: Please show the code where you are using the same `UITableViewCell` in two different `UITableView`s.

Comment: i've already edit my question with code and picture. @Dharmesh Kheni

Comment: @iPeter i've already edit my question with code and picture.

Comment: @Ajay saini your comment does make sense. i'll try to do it but i just want to know is there a way to use cell that's not in xib file. anyways thanks you very much

Comment: Did you just design you cell in one viewcontroller in storyboard and you trying to use that in another viewcontroller?

Comment: @iPeter YES, I am. is it wrong? i just thought of android recyclerview style and i thought that it would work too in swift

Comment: No it wont work, if you want to design your cell once and you want to use that in multiple uitableviews you need to design that in a xib file and register that nib to different uitableviews. I can add an answer if you want to know how to do that.

Comment: @iPeter ohhh! i see many people talk about it too so it must be the answer to my question. thanks you so much for your comment. i think i know what to do next.

Comment: Where did you register the other cell that you are using?

Comment: Thanks you everyone. just want you guy know that it does work with xib file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes** you can. You have to register it again for the new `tableView`. It is just like how you create variables using the same type. This is also a class which can be used to create objects. Doesn't matter where you want to use it.

On the other hand if you are asking if instances of the same cell which are present in a `tableView` can be **reused** in another `tableView`, then the answer is **no**, because they have only been registered for that particular `tableView`.

Comment: i've already register it in viewdidload that the code is like this. mytable.register(HistoryItemTableCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell") but it's still not working

Comment: Show your `viewDidLoad` code. You seem to be using the same reuse id for both the cells. That will not work.

Comment: override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mytable.register(HistoryItemTableCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

        ViewHistoryItem()
        mytable.dataSource = self
        mytable.delegate = self
    } // i'm only register for one cell because another cell i've created it inside my current tableview already

Comment: How? and add the code to the question as edit. No one can read this properly.

Comment: Check this pod for reusing views easily and in a type-safe way [reusable](https://github.com/AliSoftware/Reusable)